# points are replaced by a lower underline in P $ _POST

Tags: php, apache, post, php-ini

On the local server ubuntu apache, PHP7.0, mysql when I pass the $ _POST variable to the value wefwe.wf, then on the server I get wefwe_wf, how to do it normally, that is, if wefwe.wf betrayed that and in $ _POST wefwe.wf in php.ini all so

```
register_argc_argv = On
register_globals = On 
magic_quotes_gpc = On
```

Comment: magic quotes isn't available in 7.0

Comment: Also, `.` will be replaced with a `_` in request and session vars.

Comment: @AbraCadaver me need .  so as i send data with .

Comment: @iainn this is not duplicate . I just want get variable the same as i sended

Comment: @Vadim Then it's exactly a duplicate. The accepted answer to the other question explains that PHP converts dots to underscores, and the next one provides a way to access the original data.

Comment: `register_globals` This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: `magic_quotes` This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: @iainn how in php.ini ? without function in script

Comment: You cannot. There's no ini setting for that. It's a built-in PHP constraint.

Comment: @mario how him change?

Comment: **Cannot** be changed.

Comment: @mario how then work shared hosting?

Comment: No offense, but you need to spend more effort on your comments. I understand there's a slight language barrier; but your follow up questions come off as incomprehensible and a bit nagging. I'd advise you utilize the [**edit** link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50453768/edit) to explain (1) **Why** specifically you want to retain the original name. Just saying "I want" is not a useful rationale without explaining why you can't just use the renamed key name, now that you know about it. (2) After reading the duplicate twice, why you think it's not sufficient to answer your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171488/discussion-between-vadim-and-mario).